# Safari and bootstrap 4 flexbox error

Tags: html, css, safari, bootstrap-4, slick.js

Bootstrap 4 - Safari Version 10.1.2 `display:table;` and `display:table-cell; vertical-align:center;` not working on a 100% height div.

```
<div class="test-slider">
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-lg-7">
                <img src=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
                 <div style="display:table; height:100%;">
                        <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
                        <h2>Test center</h2>
                        <p>Should be centered</p>
                    </div>    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I render in chrome the height is inherited from the `.test-slider` class that has a fixed height whilst in safari it takes the contents height rather than filling the height of the div. Any ideas? I am using slick slider.

Comment: How is your corresponding css looks like?

Comment: It doesnt take 100% height, even with it set. Its a bit weird. I have as a temp fix use js to work out the height and set it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, currently I have Safari 11.0.1, but if I set the below stlye, it does center the text vertically to me.

```
.test-slider .row {
    height: 500px;
}
```

Setting the height only to `.test-slider` is not enough, since the children do not know that they should fill in that height. The 100% height set on the "table" is calculated from the height of it's parent, the `.col-md-5` div. Which, in your case does not know about the height of the `.test-slider`.

Other than that, please note that `col-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-lg-7` is totally equivalent to simply writing `col-md-7`. The same stands for `col-md-5` of course.

Also, instead of using tables, I would recommend to use the [flexbox utility classes](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/) already available in Bootstrap. That makes the markup lighter. This is an example:

```css
.test-slider .row {
    height: 300px;
}

.test {
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-slider">
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <img src=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="test col-md-5 d-flex align-items-center">
                <div>
                    <h2 class="mb-0">Test center</h2>
                    <p class="mb-0">Should be centered</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```